# How to change app id when working with Flutter and Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, rename

I have an application made in Flutter and supported by Firebase Firestore. When I created the app, I didn't care much about the app id (something.something.com), but now I need to change it. My question is, is ti possible to do this efficently, or the only way is to create a new project with a new id and copy paste everything to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@skyblazar.cc/how-to-change-the-package-name-of-your-flutter-app-4529e6e6e6fc

You also have to create a new app configuration in Firebase with your new package name.

Comment: Thank you very much!